# Iterative printing over two data types in Python

Tags: python

I often browse freely-available art on the web. Actually, I can't think of a better use for the internet than to turn it into a gigantic art gallery. When I encounter a set of pieces I quite like, I download them all to my hard drive. `wget` makes that easy, especially in combination with Python's `print` function, and I use this all the time to make a list of URLs that I then `wget`. Say I need to download a list of jpegs that run from art0 to art100 in the directory 'art,' I just tell python

```
for i in range(0,101):
    print "http://somegallery/somedirectory/art", i
```

So, this is probably a fairly simple operation in Python, and after a find-and-replace to remove whitespace, it's just a matter of using `wget -i`, but in days before I knew any Python I'd slavishly right-click and save.

Now I've got a bunch of files from Fredericks & Freiser gallery in New York that all go a(1-14), b(1-14), c(1-14), etc., up to the letter g. I could do that in 7 goes, and it would take me less time than it took to write this SO question.

That said, I want to deepen my knowledge of Python. So, given the letters a-g, how do I print a mapping of each letter to the integers 1-14?

Comment: @marcog, the way I had it before shows how I am using the code.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, everybody. Time to restart and boot up Debian again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']:
    for j in range(1,15):
        url = BASE_URL + i + str(j)
        print url
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: +1 While it looks more like Java, you can tell right away what this code does.

Comment: i actually ended up not being able to concatenate the string and the integer, but that's fine, because i just eliminated line 3 put everything into the print function

Comment: Yes, str(j) was required in the 3rd line and anyways as you did, direct print was good idea too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
['{0}{1}'.format(letter, number + 1) for letter in 'abcdefg'
                                     for number in range(14)]
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on first try, though @Spike Gronin's one did. I'm currently using Python2.6 and I didn't import anything when I tried yours. Could that be why?

Comment: @old lxfoxleigh: It should work in Python 2.6. Can you please post the exact code that you tried?

Comment: First I tried pasting what you wrote into the interpreter, then I tried writing it out myself (without making a carriage return before the second 'for')

Comment: @old lxfoxleigh: I tried it in Python 2.6 and it works fine. Can you copy what you wrote from your terminal and paste it here so I can see what you tried? Also, please post the error message you get.

Comment: I think I just need to import something. What I get is: >>> ['{0}{1}'.format(letter, number + 1) for letter in 'abcdefg'
...                                      for number in range(14)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: @old lxfoxleigh: From the documentation of str.format: `New in version 2.6.` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format ... are you *sure* you are using Python 2.6 and not something even older?

Comment: are you sure you're using python 2.6?

Comment: ahhh... sorry, guys, I've got 2 OSes on this machine and this one is actually running 2.5.2 ... i'll switch to the other one and try it out

Answer (score 1):

```
['http://somegallery/somedirectory/art/%s%s\n' % (chr(ordinal), number) for ordinal in range(ord('a'), ord('g')+1) for number in range(1, 15)]
```

Comment: I can't actually make use of this because it is not formatted the same way as the code in my question.

Comment: Still doesn't work. There are no newlines, hence it will not work to feed it to wget as a list of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need Python for this. Assuming you use bash as your shell (similar mechanisms exist in other shells), you can use brace expansion:

```
wget http://somegallery/somedirectory/art{a..g}{1..15}
```